# conflicto entre librerias android

Tags: android

estuve buscando alguna libreria que pudiese ayudarme con google directions, encontre [esta](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary), mi problema es que al momento de compilarla, tengo problemas con la libreria de picasso, sin ni siquiera agregar codigo, dejo el logatcat:

```
05-09 23:40:57.983 8028-8028/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;
                                                                                        at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.Picasso" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                        at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                ... 15 more
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
05-09 23:40:57.992 8028-8222/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1494384057984, fatal=1}]
05-09 23:40:58.396 8028-8028/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp, PID: 8028
                                                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;
                                                                                     at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.Picasso" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                     at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
                                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                            ... 15 more
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

dentro de la pagina, entrega codigo para el proguard, este es mi proguard actualmente:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Users\Javier\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-keep class com.akexorcist.** { ; }
-keep interface com.akexorcist.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { ; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.* { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
-keep class com.akexorcist.googledirection.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

espero puedan ayudarme, encontre la libreria mediante una referencia del foro en ingles.

edit: agrego el gradle como me lo solicitaron

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        Firma {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/javie/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Firma
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Firma
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':jtds-1.3.1')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.SubhrajyotiSen:library:1.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
    compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.10'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.2'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'.
```

Comment: Y si subes tu graddle?

Comment: actualize la pregunta y añadi el gradle

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no encuentra la clase principal de Picasso Library:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.squareup.picasso.Picasso" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1

Lo que necesitas es agregar la dependencia de [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) a tu archivo `app/build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Y sincronizar tu proyecto con los archivos `build.gradle`.

---

Tu proyecto es al parecer el que usa Picasso, puedes verificarlo en la clase `MainActivity.java`

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;
>                                                                                           at
>   com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:147

Comment: si, mi proyecto es el que usa picasso y la dependencia ya estaba agregada, lo que encuentro extraño es que el error se manifiesta al agregar la dependencia de la otra libreria de google directions